# Is it appropriate to use request data in model observer or model event listener

Tags: laravel, request

I want to make an observer class for one of my models for saving data.In the observer class, I need to get data from the form.I am wondering if it is appropriate to use request object in the observer class.I have never seen anyone uses it that way.